# Should prepared statements be deallocated when used inside stored procedures?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

When using prepared statements inside stored procedures, should they be deallocated at the end of the procedure or not, or does it not matter, and why?

Some code to explain:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getCompanyByName (IN name VARCHAR(100))
NOT DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  PREPARE gcbnStatement FROM 'SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE name=? LIMIT 1';
  SET @companyName = name;
  EXECUTE gcbnStatement USING @companyName;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE gcbnStatement;
END $$
```

So - should the DEALLOCATE statement be there or not? Cheers!

/Victor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html):

> A prepared statement is specific to
>   the session in which it was created.
>   If you terminate a session without
>   deallocating a previously prepared
>   statement, the server deallocates it
>   automatically.

So, no, I wouldn't bother doing it explicitly, unless you have very long-running sessions.

Comment: Thanks... While it's not much of a "why" it's certainly the best answer of the lot ;)

Comment: MySQL docs also says: "A prepared statement is also global to the session. If you create a prepared statement within a stored routine, _it is not deallocated when the stored routine ends._". Therefore, I would explicitly deallocate after finishing execution.

Comment: @Yasir wouldn't that be a good thing though, to not deallocate them? Because that way the stored procedures do not have to be recompiled when the stored procedure is used in the next database connection, would that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If you use connection pooling, it is definitely a good idea to deallocate them.

Comment: That can't be right: It would be a fundamental security risk if re-use of a connection due to pooling exposed *any* information related to a previous session. Therefore, the documented deallocation at the end of a session *must* occur before a connection is re-used from the pool.

Answer (score 0):

Deallocating Prepared statements in stored routines is best practice.

Prepared statements are global to a session and are not automatically deallocated when a stored routine ends.

If you have too many created but not deallocated prepared statement, you might encounter/exceed the max_prepared_stmt_count limit